# ASP.Net authentication and Googlebot

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-crawler, googlebot

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 web site with forms authentication enabled.  Is it possible to have Googlebot crawl my web site without getting prompted for a username/password?

Comment: Why would you want that? If the pages require authentication people doing searches won't be able to see them anyway. And if you could, you'd have to look for the user-agent, which could be spoofed, rendering your authentication meaningless.

Comment: We have a requirement to move some content under the password protected portion of the web site but they still want it to be crawled and show up in the site index.  I was pretty sure there was no way to do that without rendering the authentication meaningless but did want to confirm that.

Comment: I have update my answer - finally you can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google claims that is not wont to index page and show them on the users as available that are not, because actually they request user name and password.

It can give the option only to crawl the protect page by the AdSense so he can know what advertize to show on them

https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=37081

Other solutions that check if is bot or coming from google bot computers are not safe because they can easy spoof by the users, and also may fail to show a preview or a cache of the page.

So you need to think your site structures, what is very important and what is not, to show some part of the pages, hide some other if the user is not register, and that way google have something to index even if its not loged in.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. I suppose the links I found were dated.

Comment: This is a possible solution.  The problem is the accounts in the web site require a password change every 90 days so somebody has be responsible for manually changing the password for that account.  Also security would have to sign off on having a special account created for the crawler and it also opens a security back door as numerous people would know about the username/password for that account.

Comment: @ScottE I made a mistake, please see again my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys!  This discussion has cleared things up for me and we'll rethink our approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article:

http://www.guruofsearch.com/google-access-password-protected-site

It would be interesting to see if a google sitemap would result in pages showing up in google - but I doubt that would work either, as the pages would likely need to be crawled anyway.

And some other interesting comments here:

http://forums.searchenginewatch.com/showthread.php?t=8221